# I need to create string value depend on the length of array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to create a string value depending on the length of the array.

```
var array = ["left", "right", "top", "bottom"];
//list contain array of Object
 list.forEach((po) => {

//for example if the length of the list is 10. i need to generate the string for each loop like this 

// "left0"   for 1 loop i need this value 
// "right0"  for 2 loop i need this value
// "top0"      for 3 loop i need this value
// "bottom0"   for 4 loop i need this value

// "left1"     for 5 loop i need this value
// "right1"   for 6 loop i need this value
// "top1"     for 7 loop i need this value
// "bottom1"     for 8 loop i need this value

// "left2"   for 1 loop i need this value 
// "right2"  for 2 loop i need this value
}
```

Please help me with this issue. i am finding difficult generating string along with the number at the last and the left, right, top, bottom should be in the order and number should change after 5 loop as shown

Comment: what is the expected result you need

Comment: `for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){ ... = array[i] + ParseInt(i/array.length); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using the index of list item and length of the array.

```js
var array = ["left", "right", "top", "bottom"];

// Dummy list array
var list = new Array(10).fill(0);

list.forEach((po, i) => {
  // based on index of list calculate position in array
  // by using remainder operator
  var j = i % array.length,
    // get repetion count by simple dividing by the length
    c = Math.floor(i / array.length);
  console.log(array[j] + c)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using new ECMAScript objects such as `arrow functions` and the `fill` prototype method, along with the new `let` and `const` variable types, you can do it like this:

```js
let instructions = ['left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom'];
const ARRAY_LEN = 10;
const DUMMY_ELEM = 0;
let dummyArray = new Array(ARRAY_LEN).fill(DUMMY_ELEM);
dummyArray.map((element, index) => {
    const AUX_INDEX = index % instructions.length;
    console.log(instructions[AUX_INDEX] + Math.floor(index / instructions.length));
})
```

**EDIT**: I used `map` but you could use, of course, `forEach` or maybe, depending on your specific problem, even the [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method.

Answer (score 0):

In case you just want only one value depending on the array length. This might help you:

```js
var array = ["left", "right", "top", "bottom"];
var list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var index = (list.length - 1) % array.length;
var postfix = Math.floor(list.length / array.length);
var result = array[index] + postfix;
console.log(result);
```

In case you need list of strings:

```js
var array = ["left", "right", "top", "bottom"];
var list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var result = list.map((item, index) => array[index % array.length] + Math.floor(index / array.length));
console.log(result);
```